# Render admin form either from controller or from XML

Tags: php, xml, magento

I am implementing some code in custom module controller. After saving all things in the  database I want to render admin form. This is my controller action:

```
$this->loadLayout();
$this->getLayout()->createBlock('hello_world/adminhtml_world_edit_form')->toHtml();
```

but it's giving me:

> fatal error Call to a member function toHtml() on a non-object

I have tried this code as well in XML, savecccard is controller action where I have made some functionality and saving data:

```
<hello_world_admin_world_savecccard>
            <reference name="content">
                <block type="hello_world/adminhtml_world_edit_form" name="autoship.form"></block>
            </reference>
</hello_world_admin_world_savecccard>
```

but this gives me blank content page with header and footer only. How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

**First** you need to ensure, your module is active or not.

**Second**`toHtml() is calling in a non-object` means that, `createBlock('hello_world/adminhtml_world_edit_form')` is not working correctly.

[createBlock()](https://mage2.pro/t/topic/221) is used to create a new block and add it to the layout.

**This function has 3 parameters**:
1- type 
2- name 
3- attributes / arguments 
you have specified type as `hello_world/adminhtml_world_edit_form`. 
SO magento will look for `app/code/local/namespace/Hello_world/Block/Adminhtml/World/Edit/Form.ph‌​p` and the file should be properly declared.
Next parameter is attribute. It is optionnal.

Comment: actually hello_world is namespace_modulename. what should i use to reach exact file path?

Comment: Then you should edit your controller to `$this->getLayout()->createBlock('world/adminhtml_world_edit_form')->toHtml();`